# Unable to show number as string from parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have this code where I am trying to display some text in a label

```
let CellData:PFObject = self.data.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject
cell.titleLabel!.text = CellData.objectForKey("Title") as? String
```

The object `Title` is a String in Parse.com databse

However when i try to do that for a number using this code,

```
cell.fundsLabel!.text = CellData.objectForKey("FundsNeeded") as? String
```

Printing the value works using this code

```
println(CellData.objectForKey("FundsNeeded"))
```

How do i get number to be displayed in a label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
cell.fundsLabel!.text = String(CellData.objectForKey("FundsNeeded"))
```

Comment: Got it to work. However swift auto correct to this `cell.fundsLabel!.text = String(stringInterpolationSegment: CellData.objectForKey("FundsNeeded")!)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var fundsNeedStringInt = CellData.objectForKey("FundsNeeded") as? Int
cell.fundsLabel!.text = "\(fundsNeedStringInt)"
```